# Why FormClosing causing loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Restaurant POS, on the sales screen I create a new invoice on form load, and in closing, I delete the current invoice if there are no items inserted into the invoice but if there are items I ask the user if he is really sure he wants to close the invoice and cancel the invoice if yes, I delete the invoice if no I keep him in the sales screen.
on form closed I checked the user type if it an employee I close the entire app and if it an admin I close the form normally so he can get back to home form

but in form closing, the code executed 2 times and I couldn't figure why, knowing that the code was looping infinity but I improved the code but it's still executed 2 times now.

here is my code:

```
 private void Sales_screen_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        DBConn.Delete("Delete from invoices where ID=@ID", CommandType.Text, new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@ID", INVOICEID.ToString()) });
        if (Curent_user.Utype == "employee")
        {
            try
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Close();
            Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }

    private void Sales_screen_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GV.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var result = CmessageBox.ShowDialog(this, "confirmation", "are you sure you want to close the invoice؟");
            if (result != DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to remove your Close() inside your else?

Comment: Why the `Close`/`Dispose`/two `GC` calls in your `FormClosed` handler.  The form is closed already.  Perhaps the `GC.Collect` call makes sense, but the `WaitForPendingFinalizers` will just freeze your UI.

Comment: @MarcRoussel, ops !! I'm dumb, it's so obvious. thank you.

Comment: @Flydog57 so where I should call dispose of?? because I'm using show dialog and the form needs to be disposed of on closing.

Comment: Where you have opened that Form as dialog, the line after `ShowDialog()`; or declare the Form with a `using` statement, so it's automatically disposed. -- Remove everything from that `else { }` block and that empty `catch { }` block.

Comment: Something like `using (var dlg = new SalesScreen(param)){ if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) { /* whatever */ } }`

Comment: @Rabeea qabaha you're not dumb, sometimes small things are out of view.  Consider accepting my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing the Close() line in the else it shouldn't loop